# define recipient folder gdrive

Tags: file-upload, google-drive-api, subdirectory

I am using gdrive to upload a backup file directly into google drive, but the recipient folder should be BACKUP; I am using the command:

```
gdrive upload ./2016-12-25.tar.gz
```

where 2016-12-25.tar.gz is the backup file. As is, the file is uploaded in the main directory of google drive; what is the option to set the recipient folder to BACKUP?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try looking into the documentation [Work with Folders](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/folder) that will show how to inserting a file in a folder.

Here is the sample code for php application:

```
$folderId = '0BwwA4oUTeiV1TGRPeTVjaWRDY1E';
$fileMetadata = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile(array(
  'name' => 'photo.jpg',
  'parents' => array($folderId)
));
$content = file_get_contents('files/photo.jpg');
$file = $driveService->files->create($fileMetadata, array(
  'data' => $content,
  'mimeType' => 'image/jpeg',
  'uploadType' => 'multipart',
  'fields' => 'id'));
printf("File ID: %s\n", $file->id);
```

Now checking your code, command line code, I found a [GitHub](https://github.com/prasmussen/gdrive) and a tutorial - [How to upload a file to Google Drive from the command line](http://olivermarshall.net/how-to-upload-a-file-to-google-drive-from-the-command-line/), here is there sample code for uploading a file to a folder:

```
gdrive upload --parent 0B3X9GlR6EmbnY1RLVTk5VUtOVkk

//gdrive [global] upload [options] <path>
//-p, --parent <parent>     Parent id, used to upload file to a specific directory, can be specified multiple times to give many parents
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks, it worked. the parent folder name (although the name is misleading: parent is actually the recipient folder) is obtained from the address bar when browsing into the selected folder, for instance _https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B3X9GlR6EmbnY1RLVTk5VUtOVkk_, to follow the example.

Comment: when I use it like this: `gdrive upload --parent 0B3X9GlR6EmbnY1RLVTk5VUtOVkk path/to/someFile.someExt` the file is getting duplicated I can check with like `gdrive list --name-width 0 --absolute --query "'0B3X9GlR6EmbnY1RLVTk5VUtOVkk' in parents"`, the exact same filename in the same parent but with different id, datetime and size :(

Comment: oh, have to use `gdrive update FILEID local/path/to/File.ext`